# Как найти main в исходниках?

Tags: visual-studio, c++, функции

Мне нужно изучить исходники одной программы. Программа большая и в ней достаточно много файлов. Как найти исполняющую функцию?

// Visual Studio 2005 (нет возможности перейти на более новую)

Comment: смотри в свойствах проекта, настройках для линкера: /ENTRY:name_of_entry
где name_of_entry - твоя точка входа

Comment: у меня нет пунка /ENTRY(

Comment: @Андрей Алексеев, встречал однажды софт, который компилился из скриптов, при этом установки для линкера и компилятора присутствовали в скриптах, хотя был и проект под студию. она использовалась лишь как редактор. поищи тогда в сопутствующих файлах.

Comment: - Если проект собирается и для солюшена правильно выбран `Startup Project,` то достаточно будет одного нажатия на `Debug - Step Into` (`F7` в `General` раскладке).

 - В общем виде задача не решается, поскольку макросы типа `GTEST_MAIN(...)` и любые другие дефайны для `entry point` никто не отменял.

Comment: А зачем его искать? Если проект большой то он скорее всего выглядит просто как бесконечный циклом с обработкой ввода, объявленным классом оберткой для всего остального что там есть и инициализацией дополнительных потоков/процессов если это необходимо.

Comment: `grep main * -rn`

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваш проект не _библиотека_?

Comment: @VladD, дельный вопрос.

Comment: Если библиотека, то имеет смысл поискать заголовочный файл с ее названием и уткнуться в кучу макросов

Comment: @igumnov: в библиотеке может и не оказаться entry point (для Visual Studio: если она статическая).

Answer (score 4):

Жмем Ctrl+Shift+F и ищем по слову main. Правда, в студии это может быть _tmain.

В некоторых случаях, лучше установить себе какой-нибудь notepad++ или подобное и там воспользоваться "поиском по файлам в каталоге".

Comment: выдал результатов 200. Используются по разному, но отрыть среди них исполняемую...

на _tmain не дал результатов.

Comment: нужно попробовать уточнить. Например искать "main(" или "main (" или даже "int main("

Comment: пробовал... любые запросы со скобочкой он не находит.
походу автор все таки ,,кудесник,,

Comment: <<main >> -мэин с пробелом тоже не ищет.

Comment: пардон. тут уже я тупанул.
искать main(, main ( он ищит. но куча функций типа  Savemain()

Comment: Скачайте Unixutils и ищите grep **-w** main

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант:

1. Заупстить под дебаггером
2. Break All (Ctrl+Alt+Break)
3. Посмотреть на вкладке Threads по Call Stack`у откуда вся эта радость запускается.
4. PROFIT!

Comment: Это при условии, что оно скомпилировалось. Но есть одна проблема - если автор исходиков кудесник и обложил все макросами... и добавил что то вида `#define main nachalo_etoi_programmi`:)

Comment: @KoVadim согласен. Но это клиника и надо просто принять что в таком коде НЕ НАДО разбираться и искать main )

Comment: это спорный вопрос. Иногда может оказаться, что денежка, которую платят за разбор такого кода очень привлекательная.

Comment: я бы сказал, что денюшка привлекательная. 15 т.р. в месяц.
я стажер-второкурсник.

пришел со словами-мне деньги не нужны, дайте опыт. ну вот и впрягли разбираться в коде, что бы поддерживать

Comment: 15к за умение пользоваться поиском - это великолепно, ящитаю.

Comment: @KoVadim Если задача разовая, то ещё туда сюда. Но регулярные подобные таски повод серъёзно задуматься.

Comment: @Flammable на втором курсе нормально наверное. Там же надо человека работать в команде научить, всякие багтреккеры и прочие cvs`ы объяснить. Как раз на элементарных задачах удобно.

Comment: @Andrey Buran, работе с багтрекерами учат на первом курсе. И вообще, какое отношение к работе имеет то, чему где-то учат. Программер всю жизнь учится сам, его учить не нужно.

Comment: @Flammable Видимо я слишком стар:) 10-12 лет назад нас такому не учили, всё подобное приходилось узнавать в "боевых условиях". 
"И вообще, какое отношение к работе имеет то, чему где-то учат." Даже не знаю что вам на это ответить, на фундаментальный труд напрашивается )))

Comment: >> Даже не знаю что вам на это ответить, на фундаментальный труд напрашивается

Технологии меняются почти каждые 2 года. Девелоперы либо изучают и осваивают, либо пролетают мимо кассы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй глянуть в иерархии вызовов (если есть в твоей студии)